# paginate div tags that are created from directory php

Tags: php, html, pagination

i'm trying to paginate div tags that are created for each folder in a directory.
i have a directory called images, and within that i have sub directories.
for each of the sub directories a div tag is created. i want to paginate the div tags if more than 8 folders exist.
the code i have generating the divs is:

```
$dir = 'images';
    $dir_contents = scandir($dir);

    foreach($dir_contents as $path){
        if($path !== '.' && $path !== '..'){
            echo '<div class="box-content" >';
            echo '</div>';
            }}
```

i don't know how to go about paginating the div tags.
i quite new to php explanations, to code would be useful.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are using should be OK. To acconplish a pagination, you should use something like a counter variable.

```
$directories = 10; // number of directories
$start = 0;
if(isset($_GET['start']))
    $start = $_GET['start'] * $directories;

for($i = $start; $i < $start + $directories; $i++){
    echo $dir_content[$i];
}
```

The above code gives you the possibility to call the page with the `?start=1` parameter. Depending on the parameter you give, you will be able to switch trough the displayed directories.

Now all you have to do is removing the values "." and ".." from the array and displaying the links for the pagination.

Give me a feedback, if the code worked out.

Comment: hi thanks for reply, i managed to get the pagination working but could not get the links working, but i found some code in another question which got the links working.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879733/php-pagination-link-generation)

Comment: Good. Glad I could help.